# Adjust conditional expression to checkbox in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, if-statement, checkbox

This code using Laravel 5.4v., also adjusted `spatie/laravel-permission`.

my goal is to include conditional expression in checkbox.

[image]

How can I implement whether or not a user is a 'Super' user? 
If user has not permission 'Super' then wish to make 'Super' checkbox invisible.

Below code did not worked.

and another way too welcome:)

```
<div class='form-group'>
    @foreach ($roles as $role)
    {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles, array({!! $role == 'Super' ? "'style' => 'display:none'" : " "!!}) ) }} 
    {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}
    <br> 
    @endforeach
</div>
```

**[Solved]**

**I found the answer myself simply as below.**

```
@role('Super')
<div class='form-group'>
    @foreach ($roles as $role) 
        {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles ) }} 
        {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}
    <br> 
    @endforeach
</div>


@else
<div class='form-group'>
    @foreach ($roles as $role) 
        @if($role->name != 'Super')
        {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles ) }} 
        {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}
        @endif
   <br> 
    @endforeach
</div>
@endrole
```

Comment: maybe $user->hasRole('Super') && $role == 'Super' ? 'disabled' : '' ?

Comment: could you tell me more detailed how to adjust?

Answer (score 0):

Pointing out three errors :

- Clean up your syntax error first, you can't have a mustache inside a blade statement:

  ```
  {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles, array($role == 'Super' ? "'style' => 'display:none'" : " ")) }}
  ```
- `$role == 'Super'` will always fail because `$role` is an object. You need to call the corresponding attribute. Let's use `$role->name` instead.
- Your array is messy. If the test passes, you array will look like this : `[0 => "'style' => 'display:none'"]`.
  What you want to do is use an array only if the test passes :

  ```
  $role->name == 'Super' ? ['style' => 'display:none;'] : null
  ```

So we have:

```
{{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles, $role->name == 'Super' ? ['style' => 'display:none;'] : null) }}
```

- Finally, the third argument must be a boolean. Use the way you want to check whether a user has the corresponding role or not.

Comment: `ErrorException` `Cannot use a scalar value as an array` ;(

Comment: Fixed the ternary operator, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, but next time give us the code that work (without condition) and the code that didnt work.

```
<div class='form-group'>
@foreach ($roles as $role)
 @if ( $role->name == 'super' )
 @if($user->hasRole('super'))
{{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles ) }} 
{{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}
<br> 
@endif
 @else
 {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]', $role->id, $user->roles ) }} 
{{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}
@endif
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: no you dont need else statement, if(condition){show}

Comment: and thanks for the -1, i tried to help and my code is right^^

Comment: your code make just invisible all if user is not 'Super', please check again my question. thanks.